# Force a top line on Victory Chart axis

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

Trying to learn to use Victory Charts for a project. Given the code below it only shows tick lines at 2,4 and 6.  The data goes up to 7.6, so I'd like the top tick line of 8 to appear as well.

I can set the domain size manually, but the range could be a lot different (e.g. a graph of quarterly results vs monthly) and given Victory can automatically determine sensible axis lines I don't want to re-invent that. I put in tick count of 4 but only 3 get displayed still.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { VictoryChart, VictoryLine, VictoryContainer, VictoryTheme, VictoryAxis } from "victory";

const fixeddata = [
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 1, y: 3.2 },
    { x: 2, y: 4.9 },
    { x: 3, y: 5.3 },
    { x: 4, y: 6 },
    { x: 5, y: 7.6 }
];

export default class ExampleChart extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: fixeddata,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <VictoryChart width={600} height={400}
                containerComponent={<VictoryContainer />}>
                <VictoryLine data={this.state.data} />
                <VictoryAxis dependentAxis tickCount={4} style={
                    { grid : { stroke: "grey"}}
                } />
            </VictoryChart>
        );
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: resulting graph, with no 8 line]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to provide a [domain](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-axis/#domain) to your axis instead of setting `tickCount` prop.

To calculate domain rage you can take the item with the lowest `y` property and path through [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) to get the largest integer less than or equal to your data's `y` and also take the item with the biggest `y` property and path through [Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) to get the smallest integer greater than or equal to your data's `y`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { VictoryChart, VictoryLine, VictoryContainer, VictoryTheme, VictoryAxis } from "victory";

const fixeddata = [
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 1, y: 3.2 },
    { x: 2, y: 4.9 },
    { x: 3, y: 5.3 },
    { x: 4, y: 6 },
    { x: 5, y: 7.6 }
];

export default class ExampleChart extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: fixeddata,
        };
    }

    getAxisDomain = () => {
      const data = this.state.data.map(d => d.y);
      return [
        Math.floor(Math.min(...data)),
        Math.ceil(Math.max(...data)),
      ];
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <VictoryChart width={600} height={400}
                containerComponent={<VictoryContainer />}>
                <VictoryLine data={this.state.data} />
                <VictoryAxis 
                  dependentAxis 
                  domain={this.getAxisDomain()}
                  style={
                    { grid : { stroke: "grey"}}
                  } 
                />
            </VictoryChart>
        );
    }
}
```

A working example can be seen [here](https://react-ywavjg.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: Thanks - but I was trying to avoid manual work. Also what if the highest number was 6.9? I'd still want 8 on the top to follow the ticks.  Ultimately I could just get the source for whatever works it out in victory and re-apply it manually.